# Installing Hydro from source: package 'bullet' not found

Tags: bullet, catkin, ros-hydro, source, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! I'm in the middle of building Hydro from Source on an ARM board. I got to building the 'tf2_bullet' catkin package and ran into the following error:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'tf2_bullet'
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/tf2_bullet'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh'
==> cmake /opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_bullet -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_bullet -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro in '/opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_bullet'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- checking for module 'bullet'
--   package 'bullet' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_bullet
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_bullet/test_results
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE 
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.86
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
<== Failed to process package 'tf2_bullet': 
  Command '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh cmake /opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_bullet -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_bullet -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_bullet && /opt/ros/hydro/env.sh cmake /opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_bullet -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_bullet -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro

Command failed, exiting.
```

Anyone know a solution to this? Can I install 'bullet' from source somehow?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138321/installing-hydro-from-source:-package-%27bullet%27-not-found/) by [AndrewLawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/11631/andrewlawson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In Ubuntu, you should be able to get the package from the official repositories. If it's not packaged for your release, you can try to build and install the package (follow the instructions on the Wiki for Debian systems).

You can also have a look on the ROS page of the GumstickWiki : http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=ROS, there's a small part about bullet.

If your want more precise help, we need more details about your setup: What's you Linux distro ? What steps did you try ? And so on, the more **relevant** details, the better ;)

---

Originally posted by [RedoXyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/12196/redoxyde/) with karma: 66 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0